# OD Cost Matrix doesn't generate all the lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, network-analyst

I have 177 points of origin and 177 of destination. There's should be 31.329 lines generated by OD cost matrix, but there's only 2077 lines. I've made sure that all the points are on the traversable network, and i already checked the network with topology. I've unchecked the oneway prohibition and hierarchy option, but it still only generated 2077 lines, and when i isolated all the 128 points which don't have lines and ran OD cost matrix, only 33 from 128 points now have lines. What should i do to fix this?

the pink points are all the 128 error points which don't have lines (blue selection mark) shown in picture below

[image: the pink points are the error points]
[image: error points selection]

I'm using arcmap 10.2 with network analyst extension.

Comment: Try to solve a simple Route between a couple of points for which you didn't get any OD lines created. Does it work?

Comment: Show us how the spatial distribution of points (the spatial context) and how you used the tool. Also use proper tags in question such as the software which is being used.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov I try a couple of error points, it doesn't work and a couple of random points between error points and points which have lines, only some works.

Comment: @AndreSilva I created the origin and destination points from the central feature junction points per area

Comment: What if you don't generate the lines, only the matrix table (Output Shape Type = None in the Analysis Settings tab)? Are there missing rows too?

Comment: @GISGe still counts 2077 rows. I really have no idea..